# regex in express route not capturing full request parameter

Tags: javascript, regex, express

I'm almost positive this bug resides in the way express deals with regex patterns in route definitions, but then again, it could reside in my pattern ( I'm still a regex noob, so please excuse me ).  In my express route definition, I am trying to match a number in the route path:

```
const router = express.Router()

// pattern: ignore first capture (/) 
router.route(/^(?:\/)(\d+)$/)
  .get(...callback)
```

For now, that captured number can be of any length. So, things are working as expected when the url is: `http://localhost:8000/1234` except for the fact that the full number is not captured - when I log the request params in my callback, I get: `{ '0', '4' }`. As you can see, I get the last digit:`4` of the number:`1234`.  What is going wrong? I'm scratching my head vigorously here.  When I test my regex in both [regexr](https://regexr.com/) and the Node REPL: `/^(?:\/)(\d+)$/.exec('1234')[1] === '1234'`, it seems to be matching correctly. Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[**EDIT**]: As suggested by [@Tolsee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6880789/tolsee), I upgraded my express package from v`4.15.3` to v`4.15.5` ( the newest version ).  This seemed to fix the issue; and now, my regex pattern is working for that route.  I'm guessing that the problem lies with older express packages.

Comment: If the number in your route is a parameter then it can be captured with `router.route('/:id')`

Comment: I should have thought about this. I guess my mind is still in regex mode after using a pattern for another route.  I appreciate your response. Now, while your approach did work, I am still curious as to why the regex approach is failing here.

Comment: What version of express are you using? It works perfectly fine for `4.15.5`. And you show that `req.params` is `{'0', '4'}` isn't `req.params` a js object??

Comment: @Tolsee I just upgraded my express package. It now works in version `4.15.5`.  Previously, I was running v`4.15.3` in my app.  I guess it was an express issue.  Thanks for your insight here; and yes, `req.params` is a JS object here.  This is the answer I am going to go with as of now.  If you would be so kind to submit this as an answer, I will mark this as the correct response.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `Regexp` here, It would be better with `/:id/` ([docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters)).

If you still wanna use `Regexp`, try `/^\d+(?:\/(?=$))?$/i`

Hope it will be useful to you!

Comment: Using the name of the route parameter in the path definitely fixed the issue here, thank you.  Now, I tried your regex pattern in my route but it does not seem to work.  Also, I upgraded my express package from v`4.15.3` to v`4.15.5` ( like @Tolsee suggested ^^ ).  This seemed to resolve the issue with my regex pattern in the route definition.  I'm guessing it was an express problem.